# Finding segments / clusters in graph efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, cluster-computing

I have a graph represented using an array: [4,7,3,2,...] where each element indicates which edge index i points to.  For instance, node i=0 has a directed edge to node i=4.

I want to find all segments / clusters of nodes. A segment of nodes are nodes that are connected, either directly or through other nodes. For instance, for the array [3,2,1,0], there are two segments, 0-3 and 1-2.  Hence, the result should be in the format = {0:[0,3], 1:[1,2]}.

I have already implemented an algorithm using the following overall structure:

```
while (numberOfNodesToCheck !=0):
   for:...
   while true:
      finding all nodes a node can reach
      break if no more nodes to reach
```

Does anybody have a more clever solution method?

Comment: What do you mean by "clusters" or "segments" here? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Updated the question now.

Comment: What if you got something like [1, 1, 1, 1]? What would the clusters be then?

Comment: Then they will all be in the same cluster.